# loop with two columns in a text file

Tags: php, text, for-loop

this is a sample text file called `data.txt`

```
john engineer
mathew IT consultant
elan Vice president
emili administrator
joicee nurse
```

---

```
$lines = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    foreach ($lines as $names => $designation) { 

    //I am not sure above one is right?? then what??
    }
```

I want this to be loaded in two variables

```
$names = john;
$designation = Engineer;
```

and loop through...

Comment: : See my code..It working!!! Test it

Comment: @Manish Let your code stand on its own merits, don't spam comments trying to sell your answer

Answer (score 3):

The lines in `$lines` aren't a 'name' => 'designation' map by default; you have to manually break the lines apart.

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this. You'll have to add `2` as the optional "limit" parameter, to insure the lines are broken up at only the first space:

```
$lines = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  list($name, $designation) = explode(' ', $line, 2);
}
```

Without the limit, lines like `"elan Vice president"` would be broken up as `array("elan", "Vice", "president")` instead of `array("elan", "Vice president")`.

Comment: limit=1 will return an array with single value

Comment: Better solution. +1 after I refreshed a few times and you got the limit = 2 right (limit is the number of elements in the returned array, not the number of delimiters to hit)

Answer (score 2):

If your format is always using space as delimiter between `$name`, an `$designation`, this might work

```
foreach ($lines as $line_number => $line) 
{
  $space = strpos($s, ' ');
  $name  = substr($s, 0, $space);
  $designation = substr($s, $space+1);
}
```

Comment: I was typing this SAME solution :) +1

Answer (score 0):

If "names" and "designations" are separate with tabulation, you can use something like this :

```
foreach ($lines as $line) { 
  list($name, $designation) = explode("\t", $line);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tty following code. Its work::

```
$lines = file('new.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
list($name[], $job[]) = explode(' ', $line,2);
}
foreach($name as $n=>$value)
 echo "Name= ".$name[$n]." Job=".$job[$n]."<br>";
```